# How to render a CIImage with indexed colorspace in UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgcolorspace

I'm trying to convert an image coming from a video stream (CVImageBuffer) to a given set of predefined colors. Below I'm first converting the stream to a CIImage with a indexed colorspace, then converting the CIImage to a UIImage, but this final conversion gives the following error: `[render] Could not support source colorspace: Indexed Colorspace 0x281608ba0`.

Any idea of how to get this effect (like a Posterize effect, but with defined colors)?

```swift
let palette: [UInt8] = [
    0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 255
    0, 255, 0,
    255, 0, 0,
    255, 255, 255]

let indexedColorSpace = CGColorSpace(indexedBaseSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                     last: palette.count - 1,
                                     colorTable: palette)!

let image = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: videoPixelBuffer,
                    options: [CIImageOption.colorSpace: indexedColorSpace])

let context = CIContext()
let cgImage = context.createCGImage(image, from: image.extent)!

indexedImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```

[EDIT]

After [matt comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61425608/how-to-render-a-ciimage-with-indexed-colorspace-in-uiimageview?noredirect=1#comment-108661249), I've added the rendering through a CIContext, but still get the same colorspace error…

Comment: The problem is this line: `indexedImageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: image)` You can’t just wrap a CIImage in a UIImage and display it in an image view. You have to actually render the CIImage into a real UIImage first. Either that or display the CIImage directly using Metal.